# Why is this for loop only doing one iteration?

Tags: php, html, for-loop

For some reason this loop only does one iteration and makes only 1 row. Can anyone spot an error?

```
        for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . ($min + ($i * 5)) . "</td>";
            for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++){
                echo "<td>" . $min . "</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
```

Comment: change second for loop `i` to someother name like `j` or `k`

Comment: I actually cannot believe I did not notice that. Very sorry

Answer (score 0):

You are using same variable in both loops (`$i`). Use another variable in second loop.